# Error deploying NextJS application on AWS Amplify after upgrading Next library

Tags: aws-amplify, next.js13

I have a NextJS application deployed on AWS Amplify that uses Next version 13.2.3 and the Google fonts that come with the framework, importing them with the command

`import { Poppins } from 'next/font/google`

Recently, I upgraded Next to version 13.3.0 and started having issues when trying to deploy the application on AWS Amplify. Although the application builds without problems on my local environment, I'm receiving the following error when trying to deploy on Amplify:

[image: 1]

Any ideas on what could be causing the error? I would appreciate any help you can provide.

update nextJS and deploy app to amplify